# PHP filemtime returns current date

Tags: php, laravel, filemtime

I want to get modified date of the file that is uploaded but it returns current time (which I guess it's because `filemtime` returns modified date of temp file so long story short how can I get the true modified date?

here is my code it's (laravel framework)

```
$file = $request->file;
dd(filemtime($file));
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, you could use `Storage::lastModified($path)` to get modified date of the file, and don't forget add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;`, hope it will help you guys.

Comment: Could be useful to include a link to the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#file-metadata

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// outputs e.g.  somefile.txt was last modified: December 29 2002 22:16:23.

$filename = 'somefile.txt';
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "$filename was last modified: " . date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($filename));
}
?>
```

The above code worked for, try it from your end, let me know, if any errors.

Comment: well I want too get `filemtime` of uploaded file not a file in my directory beside I tried to move the file to my directory and use the above code but it still returns current time

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use protogenous php, you could use filemtime(storage_path("app/yourPath").$file) to get last modified date of the file. Because the `storage_path()` could get the real path that restore your file. Hope it will help you.